# Best way to generate exponential variate in java

Tags: java, variables, exponential

Anyone knows how can I generate a set of random exponential variates in java? Thanks in advance

I have not tried any code yet.
I have one var known and another one random.

I have this scenario,
I have a known number, and I want to generate a set of random exponential numbers in range 1-20.

Comment: Got any code have you tried anything yet?

Comment: is something like this http://mymathlib.webtrellis.net/functions/probability/exponential_random_variate.html that you want?

Comment: could you be a little more specific?  For example, what needs to be random does this need to be something like (known number)^(random number) or is it (random number)^(known number), or (random number)^(random number)